# How to remove Highcharts.com at right bottom corner from the chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to remove highcharts.com from the result of the chart. Which is at the right bottom corner

[At the bottom right corner I need to remove or replace with out url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3QsT.png)

Comment: Use this property: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits.enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that using Settings 'credits' to false or you can set your own URL in Highcharts .
such as 
`

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function(){
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart( {

        chart: {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", 
            marginTop: 50,            
            type: 'pie',
            renderTo: 'chart1' 
        },
       credits: {
      enabled: false
   },
 ... 

 ....//other chart data//
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following to change the url:

```
credits: {
    text: 'Example.com',
    href: 'http://www.example.com'
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/credits/href/) from the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits.href), where you can also see how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Highchart by default puts a credits label in the lower right corner of the chart. This can be changed using these options.

[Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/fzeqx8dv/2/)

```
  credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: { 
            enabled: false
      },
```